# Unable to return array from SQL, only returning mysqli_stmt

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php-8

I've been doing SQL for over a year now, and have became completely stuck. For some reason, i'm not able to return any values from this table as I get the error

```
mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, mysqli_stmt given
```

I'm completely floored as to why this is happening, as i've used these kind of queries in the past
The code i'm using is

```php
  $user = "testuser";
  $q = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
  $q->bind_param("s", $user);
  $q->execute();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q))
      var_dump($row);
```

If I do var_dump($q), then I get an object object(mysqli_stmt)#3 (10) with no errors and the correct amount of fields. I'm just not able to read anything from this for some reason.

Thanks!

Comment: For a start, your error points at something completely different `Argument #1 ($result)` where as your code shows `$q`

Comment: @Jaquarh That is the only code in my file - I don't make a reference to $result anywhere, $result i'm guessing is the name of the variable in the SQLi lib, as you can see in the PHP documentation for this function - it doesn't mean my variable is called $result

Comment: The full error is
 Uncaught 
```TypeError: mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, mysqli_stmt given in /public_html/testing/profile.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /public_html/testing/profile.php(7): mysqli_fetch_array() #1
```

Comment: If i use a query instead of prepare bind_param this seems to return correctly, however I would like to use bind_param to prevent injection. So it seems like SQL just won't execute the code for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call a `get_result()` before you can fetch your data

```
  $user = "testuser";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $user);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->get_result();
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      var_dump($row);
  }
```

PS. better to use `fetch_assoc()` instead of `fetch_array()`